# geth: shh_newIdentity does not exists/is not available

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, whisper

I'm trying out whispers with `web3` and `geth` on a private testnet. I'm just running the following code taken from [Ethereum Whisper wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Overview).

```
function sendWhisper() {
    var shh = web3.shh;
    var appName = "My silly app!";
    var myName = "Gav Would";
    var myIdentity = shh.newIdentity();
}
```

However, I'm getting this problem:

> app.js:5318 Uncaught Error: The method shh_newIdentity does not exist/is not available

I'm having a wild guess that there is something wrong with `geth`. According to [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/310) the JSON RPC `shh_newIdentity`, should have been implemented already. Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't notice that, but hey! First post on ethereum stackexchange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to start `geth` with the `--shh` parameter.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth help | grep shh
--shh      Enable Whisper
```

Without the `--shh` parameter:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ geth --datadir test console
...
>   var shh = web3.shh;
undefined
>   var appName = "My silly app!";
undefined
>   var myName = "Gav Would";
undefined
>   var myIdentity = shh.newIdentity();
The method shh_newIdentity does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:20
```

With the `--shh` parameter:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ geth --datadir test --shh console
>   var shh = web3.shh;
undefined
>   var appName = "My silly app!";
undefined
>   var myName = "Gav Would";
undefined
>   var myIdentity = shh.newIdentity();
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that, in my case, I need to add shh to --rcpapi as well: `--rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,shh"`

Comment: Update for Whisper v5 - See https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/874 and https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper

Answer (score 0):

In geth you need to specify the flags --shh and --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,shh"